# Adding custom field in Google custom search engine

Tags: html, css, google-search-api

I had created a custom search engine on Google but the problem is that it gives you a Text-field having Google logo etc.I want to have my own text field at my site and when i click on search the it calls the Google custom search Engine but there should be no Google predefined text field there.Please tell me how can i do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call Google Search API with your arguments that will return you JSON response.
http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/start.html
Hope this will help you

Comment: Do I need to change the CSS too?

Answer (score 1):

I believe if you want to remove the logo you have to pay for the search engine.